# Error 1 Non-invocable member 'System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

String[] files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(directoryToSearch, fileNameToFind, SearchOption.AllDirectories());

Comment: Remove the parentheses after `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

Comment: i used above code in files_search_app and then wen i run my code i end up in this error

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, you can't invoke `SearchOption.AllDirectories` as a method, because it isn't a method.  I think you want this:

```
String[] files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(directoryToSearch, fileNameToFind, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Putting parentheses after something tells the compiler that it should *execute* that something as a method.  So you were essentially just confusing the compiler.  `SearchOption.AllDirectories` is a value, not a method.